# Transferring data from server to multiple clients sequentially

Tags: c#, algorithm, networking, udp

I've an application in which I want to include the networking module for it to be able to send the data to multiple clients (different machines on same WiFi network). This application generates image data for each client every hour and has to send this data to 10 different clients which are on the same WiFi network. When the data transfer to all the clients finishes, all the clients have to simultaneously display the data on the screens.

I've not developed any networking modules earlier and have minimal experience in this. My initial search just showed that I probably should be transferring the data to all the clients first somehow and then broadcast a signal for the clients for them to show the data simultaneously. I wanted to get an idea of the approach that should be followed for something like this - how would the server send the image data to all the clients?
 
I think in my case, it's more of time-critical than reliable data transfer needed, so I'd be inclined to use UDP to get faster transfers. I understand that I can send the data to client in a queuing fashion but is there a mechanism of knowing which clients on the network are waiting for the data? Is there a `client-register-with-server` kind of thing through which I can keep a note of all the clients where the data has to be sent? Is this `client-register` thing possible in UDP?

Through my application, I'll be able to create a UDP Server Socket on a specific port - but how will multiple clients notify **sequentially** (every client can't notify together obv.) to my server about their availability on the network and how do I then keep a note of their host addresses/ports?

Answer (score 1):

just another approach: create number of threads equal to number of users and load it from thread pool, for each client, one thread will be allocated and will make a tcp connection to send the image and have a tcp listener on each client that will listen for any data retrieval from server.

Answer (score 0):

I advocate use of **TCP** over **UDP** if the data needs to sent reliably otherwise **UDP** would be sufficient . In your case it seems that image data must be reliably sent so use **TCP**. As you are dealing with multiple clients it would be good to be responsive so you should divide the data in chunks and then send it over network using round robin or Shortest first scheduling of a queue of client requests. At client side collect the data and render it as it comes rather then waiting for whole data. To achieve dynamic rendering use PNG or JPEG file formats. Use multithreading if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think in my case, it's more of time-critical than reliable data transfer needed, so I'd be inclined to use UDP to get faster transfers. I understand from your response that I can send the data to client in a queuing fashion, for which I wanted to ask if there's a mechanism of knowing which clients on the network are waiting for the data. Is there a kind of `client-register-with-server` thing through which I can keep a note of all the clients where the data has to be sent? Is this `client-register` kind of thing possible in UDP?

Comment: @user1240679 yes it is possible whenever you make a connection it creates special socket descriptor for the connection referring to the client. Your registry will contain all these socket descriptors which can use to send udp packets to. i dont no about c# but c++ has this facility

Comment: I edited my question to understand how multiple clients can notify sequentially (every client can't notify together obviously) to my server about their availability on the network and how do I then keep a note of their host addresses/ports? It'd be good to get a link where I can read this information relevant to C# as well.